# Azure DevOps - Boards - Link Work Item with Deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-boards

I can't make Deployment Widget of a Work item view to work.

I have a Product Backlog item defined as follows:

[image]

As you can see i have linked this work item in the "Development" widget to master branch

I also enabled my release pipeline to log to Report deployment status to Boards

[image]

And despite multiple commits to master triggering build and that triggering release still in my ticket the Deployment widget does not show those releases. I must miss some setup work here.

I was expecting something similar to this:
(Screenshot of Tim Corey)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So my initial idea was invalid. This link is based on the text of the commit.

Work item has id 16.

I commit code with a message "Fix invalid user registration link #16".

Then the pipelines are executed and then the release is bound to the work item in the Deployment widget.

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOSkX.png)